# Bumblebee Configurator GUI Set-Up

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, nouveau

Installed Bumblebee Configuator GUI.

I choosed "Nvidia" driver and "Exit at quit" thing to test it. It saved. But how do I know its really Nvidia driver that's in use?

The other option was "Nouveau", this didn't work, got "Nouveau doesn't excist". What's that all about? Should I write something else in "Nouveau" tab? For Kernel Driver? Its now just "Nouveau" and Xorg config file is xorg.conf.nouveau...

In system setting its show on graphic: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
I think that's normal whatsoever, dont think there will be anything else there..

But the Intel HD graphic card is found, when lspci in terminal (nvidia too)..

Any tips?!

Comment: Well, don't know if the configurator works, the bumblebee indicator (extension) didn't tell me it was active. When I run "optirun glxspheres" in terminal it activates and seems to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nVidia driver is only used when you use `optirun`, so a easy way to check if you are using nVidia driver is using `glxinfo`:

```
$ optirun glxinfo | grep -i nvidia
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 310.14
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler

$ glxinfo | grep -i nvidia
# No output at all
```

If you get any output then you are using the nVidia driver.

Comment: got this: `axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ glxinfo | grep -i nvidia      
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ optirun glxinfo | grep -i nvidia         
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.88
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$`

Comment: Then it is using the correct driver.